# Is it possible to listen bluetooth states in Android using Monkey runner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, android-bluetooth

Can anyone kindly let me know if the Bluetooth state(ie., ON, OFF, Connected, Searching etc)
be detected using the help of Monkey Runner.

Answer (score 0):

The monkeyrunner tool helps you control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code. It offers some useful image-comparison based testing solutions. You can check the state of the Bluetooth (On/Off) by taking a screen capture of the Bluetooth settings screen and comparing it with a reference image. The link [here](http://android-test-tw.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/android-monkeyrunner-with-jythan.html) demonstrates a simple example on this topic. Have a look at it and see if it is helpful for you.